# How to find the equilibrium point of this system?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes

I've been looking for the equilibrium point with the help of SymPy (Python Library). Even one of the equations cannot be found with SymPy because the solution is very long. I'm curious about the equilibrium point and stability of this system.

\begin{align*}
    \frac{dx_{1}}{dt} &= a_{1}+k_{7}x_{5}(\frac{x_{1}}{K+x_{1}})+k_{2}x_{1}x_{2}-d_{1}x_{1}-d_{7}x_{1}x_{5} \\
    \frac{dx_{2}}{dt} &= a_{2}+k_{4}x_{4}-d_{2}x_{2}-k_{8}x_{2}x_{3} \\
    \frac{dx_{3}}{dt} &= a_{3}x_{6}-d_{3}x_{3}-k_{1}x_{1}x_{3} \\
    \frac{dx_{4}}{dt} &= a_{4}+k_{10}x_{3}-d_{6}x_{2}x_{4}-d_{4}x_{4}+k_{6}x_{6}-k_{3}x_{2} \\
    \frac{dx_{5}}{dt} &= a_{5}-d_{5}x_{5} \\
    \frac{dx_{6}}{dt} &= a_{6}x_{6}+a_{7}x_{5}-k_{5}x_{4}x_{6}
\end{align*}

Comment: You get a system of polynomials of degrees $3,2,2,2,1,2$. This can have up to 48 different solutions, which in general do not have symbolic representations. One could do a reduction to a univariate polynomial, but sympy does not have the required Gröbner or Kronecker functionality for it.